# Passing a list to a multiple-arity function in DrRacket (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, racket, lcm, arity

I am trying to generate the least common multiple for all numbers from 1 to n as described in [OEIS-A003418](https://oeis.org/A003418).  In the DrRacket REPL I'm using the following code:

```
(lcm (apply values (build-list 256 add1)))
```

Which gives me a "result arity mismatch" error (expected 1, received 256).  When I omit `lcm` I get a sequence from 1 to 256 output to the console.  I'm uncertain as to the cause of the arity mismatch, since `lcm` is supposed to be able to take arbitrarily many arguments (according to [the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._lcm%29%29)), and `apply` seems to be doing what I would expect when it is the outermost function and not an input to `lcm`.  What am I missing?  Also, if there is an easier way to write the LCM from 1 to n please feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between fixed arity and non-fixed arity when you use `apply`:

```
(apply lcm (build-list 256 add1))
```

Comment: Ah. I see I was misunderstanding how apply is used.  Thanks!